# Why is an extra login required to use AppTransaction with iOS 16.0?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, storekit

In the app I am working on I have the need to check what version the user purchased the app first at. It seems that Apple's AppTransaction (available starting in iOS 16.0 as part of StoreKit) is made just for that purpose. But I noticed that when I first call "AppTransaction.shared", a "Sign in with Apple ID" prompt is coming up that asks for Apple ID and password.

While the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction/4020518-shared) refers to the fact that the user must be authenticated with the App Store, I don't see any reference to throwing up this dialog box.

On my device I have already authenticated to the App Store, and have downloaded apps to verify this.

If only password was asked for security purposes then this dialog might make sense, but allowing the user to enter in another Apple ID (different from the one they are actually signed up via the device's Settings) seems like a bad idea. Furthermore, this is a pretty bad experience to users to have them authenticate again.

If anyone has any idea why this dialog is being shown, and if there is any way to get the version the app was first downloaded at w/o such a popup, that would be great.

Comment: Running into the same issue ... did you get any answers to this problem?

Comment: No unfortunately I ended up shelving this effort for the time being since I couldn't get around it.

Comment: So what is the alternative you tried that works?

Comment: I haven't found a good workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are testing IAP (in-app purchase) in a sandbox environment, while the application is in development phase Apple gives you a way to test IAP and they call it Sandbox, you can not test Sandbox purchases with your regular AppStore account for this purpose you need a special account created through [app store connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) this tool is part of apple developer program.

And once your app get approved and gets live on AppStore you can buy with your regular account and it won't ask you to add email or password.